# Any techniques to better break down rails associations? (specific example given)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Thanks for taking a look!

I'm building my first "on my own" app after reading the Depot book and the rails tutorial and working though both. I'm finding it difficult to get my associations worked out since there's so many of them in my current practice project. Here's the overview, it's basically a simple NFL pickem app:

A "User" logs in (devise) and sees a list of "Games" for this week.    (let's say NFL games for example).
A "User" can make their "Picks" for    those games with that first screen mentioned and submit them for the    week.
A "Game" has 2 teams associated with it.
A "Game" has a    "result" (torn on having a Results model or just using a result    column in games table here). 
A "Week" has several "Games" in it which    are picked.

After picks are made they are allowed to see everyone    elses picks also but that's not really relevant here.

So as you can see above there are several relationships that I need to specify and I'm having a really difficult time working them all out. Also I found myself wanting to make scaffolds for each (I know right?) but I don't think that's the right answer here.

Also, once worked out is there a good order to take with them? Like in this case I figure it's a good idea to start with the "Teams" so I can add "Weeks" and "Games" to each of those weeks. But I'm just really lost and overwhelmed I guess. Any tips on how to start tackling this problem? Thanks so much for the help all!

(please let me know if you want to see code, but I figure this is more of a process / fundamental question than a "give me a solution to my specific problem" question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often handy to break apart all the different objects and then ask yourself how each is related. You've already done all that with what you've said above, so then it's just a matter of translating that to code:

- Users can make picks means that a user `has_many` picks.
- Picks are for games means that a pick `belongs_to` a game.
- A game has two teams (let's say home and away) so a game `belongs_to` two different teams.
- A week has several games so a week `has_many` games.

Since the result can be either a relationship or a column, that means the game `has_one` result.

Then you just need to reverse those associations for the other models. A `has_one` on one end means a `belongs_to` on the other. A `belongs_to` on one end means either a `has_many` or a `has_one` on the other.

The key is really understanding the 3 different associations - `belongs_to`, `has_many`, and `has_one` - and how they translate to English.

The result would come out something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :picks
end

class Pick < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :picks
  belongs_to :home_team, :class_name => "Team"
  belongs_to :away_team, :class_name => "Team"
  belongs_to :week
  has_one :result
end

class Week < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :home_games, :class_name => "Game"
  has_many :away_games, :class_name => "Game"
end

class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Trying to wrap my head around the named relationships though. Would this basically mean that in the "Games" model I'd need fields named "home_team_id" and "away_team_id"?

Comment: Thanks! This was insanely helpful. Guess I was just too wrapped up in it.